# Can you build vsc extensions in vanilla js?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to make a plugin for Visual Studio Code, but my `extension.js` file isn't showing any sign of work.

I have the following file hierarchy:

```
src/index.js
src/syntax.json
package.json
```

where as in package.json, the following configuration (there is more to package.json, only these are question-relevant):

```json
{
  // The JS file, doesn't work
  "main": "src/index.js",

  // The syntax file, works
  "contributes": {
    "grammars": [{
      "language": "sc",
      "scopeName": "source.sc",
      "path": "./src/syntax.json"
    }],
  }
}
```

I have also tried `./src/index.js`, it didn't work either. `index.js` as of now just contains a basic example taken from the [Semantic Highlight Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide)

Comparing other examples, I noticed that most were written in typescript, and had the following for main in package.json

```json
{
  // Bundled?
  "main": "./out/src/index"
}
```

### Is typescript forced for visual studio extensions, or is vanilla JS possible?

Comment: I have all my extensions written in plain JS, VSC only runs plain JS, maybe `"main": "./src/index.js"`

Comment: How can `extension.js` show any sign of work, if you don't use it?

Comment: @rioV8 No, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MikeLischke i have just named the file index.js, i just wanted to point out that others use typescript

Comment: have you tried the plain JS example extension

Comment: @Mark none, activation events would only be needed for published extensions anyway, right?

Comment: "index.js as of now just contains a basic example taken from the Semantic Highlight Guide", so what exactly does it contain? The TypeScript based extensions are compiled to JavaScript (that's why you saw `"main": "./out/src/index"`), so there isn't any difference if you write yours in JavaScript. What matters is whether you write it the right way.

Comment: @LexLi so there's no bundling in the background by vsc? As in, something is wrong with the index file, you mean?

Comment: You need an activation event to test an extension, just use `"*"` for testing.